# Javascript requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

I have two checkboxes on selection of each one will raise a ajax request in order to get response from server. I need to call a method only once when there is atleast 2 seconds gap after the last request is made. Any idea? This means i do not want to call the methods when checkboxes are clicked continously for less than 2 seconds gap. How can i cancel the request made if the time gap between the requests in less than 2 seconds. Note that  i want the method to be fired only once after the last request is not followed by other requests for 2 seconds.

```
var timeout; 
clearTimeout(timeout); 
timeout = setTimeout(function () { // call method }, 2000);
```

Comment: Apart from those two checkboxes, do you have some code too?

Comment: var timeout;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        // call method
   }, 2000);

Comment: please add the code to your question, not in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Note that i wan to excecute the method only once for the last request made.*

You don't show any code, but assuming you already have a function `doAjax()` that does the ajax request, you can ensure it isn't called until two seconds after the last click in any two second period by using the [`setTimeout()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to do something like this:

```
var timerID;
document.getElementById("yourCheckboxIdHere").onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    timerID = setTimeout(doAjax, 2000);
};
```

Note that `doAjax` does *not* have parentheses after it when passed as a parameter to the `setTimeout()` function.

If you need to pass parameters to your `doAjax()` function change the line with `setTimeout()` to:

```
    timerID = setTimeout(function(){
       doAjax(parameters, go, here);
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: but the above method is firing the doAjax() method everytime.I have mutiple checkboxes calling doAjax() method when clicked. i want the method to be fired only once after the last request is not followed by other requests for 2 seconds.

Comment: The code I've shown works fine for me with two checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/Mb7j5/ Only one call to `doAjax()` in any given two-second period regardless of which checkboxes are clicked and what order they're clicked. (I did assume in my answer that you'd be able to figure out how to extend it to work for two checkboxes...) Make sure the `timerID` variable is defined _outside_ the click handler (unlike the code you added to your question which has it defined right before `clearTimeout()`).